# How to display target task times in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have a CruiseControl.NET configured project and would like to find out how long each task took to be completed.

My cconfig.net looks like this:

> ```
>     <targetList>
>         <target>compile</target>
>         <target>test</target>
>         <target>pack</target>
>         <target>send</target>
>         <target>twitterify</target>
>     </targetList>
> ```

And how now for gods sake display how long each task was executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following in your `<project>`?

```
    <publishers>
        <xmllogger logDir="log" />
    </publishers>
```